# How to replace substrings in a Dataframe column, but only at the start of the strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to replace specific characters in a data frame just if the string of the column starts with the characters specified. I mean, the df is as below:

| UBICACION | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| AL03 | Joe |
| FL03 | Maria |
| AL07 | Karla |
| DAL5 | Marco |

The desired output would be:

| UBICACION | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| **FL03** | Joe |
| FL03 | Maria |
| **FL07** | Karla |
| DAL5 | Marco |

This is my try:

```
df['UBICACION'] = df['UBICACION'].replace ("FL","AL")
```

The last sentence is not working, cause' it changes all the word, it just keeps the specified characters

Hope you can help me, I'm a little bit new on this. Best regards.

Comment: When do you want to change the FL to AL?

Comment: Every Time that the string starts with "FL" :)

Comment: I edited the title of the question to reflect the question you appear to be actually asking. Please feel free to re-correct it if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**`DataFrame.replace`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) includes a `regex=True` option, so you can use `^AL`:

```py
df['UBICACION'] = df['UBICACION'].replace('^AL', 'FL', regex=True)


#   UBICACION   NAME
# 0 FL03        Joe
# 1 FL03        Maria
# 2 FL07        Karla
# 3 DAL5        Marco
```

Comment: WOW it really worked, just a quick question, why does '^' is used for?

Comment: when `^` is at the beginning of a regex, it's a special regex character that means "beginning of the line"

Comment: here's a decent summary of other [special characters in regular expressions](https://users.pja.edu.pl/~jms/qnx/help/watcom/wd/regexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
df["UBICACION"] = df["UBICACION"].apply(lambda x: f"FL{x[2:]}" if x.startswith("AL") else x)
```